# Merging two arrays to work with JS templating (MustacheJS, Handlebars, Dust)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, handlebars.js, underscore.js

I am linking to an external JSON file and wish to convert the two arrays within it, into one single array for use with JS templating frameworks such as MustacheJS, Handlebars, Dust etc.

This seems to be possible using `extend` in Underscore but I have found another possibility called `concat`, but this only appears to demonstrated on two separate arrays rather than one file https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Is it possible to merge two arrays from a single source for use in JS templating?

Here is the JSON
http://myjson.com/kjs8l

So in essence, converting:

```
[
  [
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/i0lfddlghaiwfqlvlqay/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS"
    },
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/cmuof8adhfipkvd0f43r/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "sitename": "Nike",
      "sitetitle": "Nike. Just Do It.. Nike.com",
      "siteurl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/"
    }
  ]
]
```

into

```
[
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/i0lfddlghaiwfqlvlqay/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS"
    },
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/cmuof8adhfipkvd0f43r/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM"
    }
    {
      "sitename": "Nike",
      "sitetitle": "Nike. Just Do It.. Nike.com",
      "siteurl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/"
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you want afterwards? A file with the given content? Or an array in JS?

Comment: Just use/load the merged array in MustacheJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you read the file in JS then you can just use the concat method:

```
var arrays = [
[
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/i0lfddlghaiwfqlvlqay/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-vortex-shoe-fmq6pS"
    },
    {
      "productimage": "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/cmuof8adhfipkvd0f43r/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM.jpg",
      "producturl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-95-shoe-XPTbV2mM"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "sitename": "Nike",
      "sitetitle": "Nike. Just Do It.. Nike.com",
      "siteurl": "https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/"
    }
  ]
];
var mergedArrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
    mergedArrays=mergedArrays.concat(arrays[i]);
}
console.log(mergedArrays);
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/91nmx4uh/

Is this what you want?